# "Il faut que vous y alliez". C'est vrai

Tags: sens, traduction, expressions, subjonctif, ordre-des-mots

J'ai utilisé le subjonctif parce que la phrase communique une notion de  nécessité.

Mais, est-ce que j'aurais dû mettre le verbe après « que » ?

Answer (score 2):

On utilise toujours le subjonctif après « il faut que ».
Non, le sujet passe d'abord; en utilisant la construction sans «  que » le verbe, qui est alors à l'infinitif, passe directement après « il faut ». Mais dans ce cas il n'y a pas de sujet du verbe et le seul sujet est les ujet impersonnel « il ».

- Il faut que tu ailles à la plage.
- Il faut aller à la plage. (*Le «vrai sujet», c'est à dire plutôt la ou les personnes qui font l'action d'aller se déduit du contexte.*)

Answer (score 2):

Je ne suis pas sûr de comprendre ce que la notion de nécessité, spécifiquement, vient faire dans le choix du mode. Plus simplement, je crois qu'il convient de revenir à quelques observations de base :

1°) Le français courant moderne a largement imposé le subjonctif comme mode naturel d'une proposition subordonnée introduite par "que". Cet usage du subjonctif à toutes les sauces, même quand il ne s'impose pas logiquement, est du pain béni pour un francophone débutant : il est possible d'utiliser le subjonctif présent sans réfléchir dans 99.99% des cas après "que", quand bien même ce serait techniquement impropre.

2°) Les formes imparfaites et plus-que-parfaites du subjonctif sont virtuellement mortes, à tel point qu'elles ne sont plus guère employées que comme élément de statut dans tel ou tel aréopage, ou pour créer un effet comique ou archaïsant. Elles ont donc, elles aussi, cédé le pas au présent du subjonctif qui ne conserve plus que sa valeur modale en abdiquant toute valeur temporelle.

3°) Pour quelqu'un qui voudrait pousser la réflexion plus loin, je définirais surtout le bon usage du subjonctif dans ce cas de figure "en creux" : l'indicatif étant le mode de la réalisation, dans les rares occasions où le subjonctif présent gagnerait à être remplacé sans que cette substitution choque excessivement l'oreille de l'interlocuteur, il s'agit de projections passées, qui s'appuient sur l'indicatif pour exprimer leur certitude (puisque inscrites dans le passé). Ainsi, il est tout-à-fait juste, bien que d'usage aujourd'hui assez anecdotique, de dire "après que nous eûmes mangé, mon hôte me quitta pour la sieste". "Après que nous avons mangé" est moins littéraire, mais d'un emploi également correct.

*TL;DR : In case of emergency, break glass and use* subjonctif présent *after "que". Should prove to be your best bet in most instances.*